# Rust implementation of split_at_mut

Tags: rust

I've been reading the Rust Book, and in the section about Unsafe Rust, it shows how to implement a simple version of the `split_at_mut` method. The given implementation is :

```
use std::slice;

fn split_at_mut(values: &mut [i32], mid: usize) -> (&mut [i32], &mut [i32]) {
    let len = values.len();
    let ptr = values.as_mut_ptr();

    assert!(mid <= len);

    unsafe {
        (
            slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mid),
            slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.add(mid), len - mid),
        )
    }
}
```

However, I came up with this :

```
fn split_at_mut(values: &mut [i32], mid: usize) -> (&mut [i32], &mut [i32]) {
    let len = values.len();
    assert!(mid <= len);

    let begin = &mut values[..mid] as *mut [i32];
    let end = &mut values[mid..] as *mut [i32];
    
    unsafe {
        (&mut *begin, &mut *end)
    }
}
```

which produces (as far as I know) the same result, but is, in my opinion, easier to read.

So what makes the given solution "better" than mine ? Does my solution has a safety (or other) issue ? Is the given solution, in fact, easier to read ? Is it about extending this method over other slices ? Is it about coding style and "good practice" ?

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: It's only my opinion, but I find switching back and forth between * and & more difficult to read than explicit calls to `as_mut_ptr()` and `from_raw_parts_mut()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I think is going on with why (as another answer wrote) Miri rejects your code:

```rust
(
    slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mid),
    slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.add(mid), len - mid),
)
```

In this case, you are constructing two non-overlapping `&mut` references from a pointer that came from the single `&mut` reference `values`.

```rust
let begin = &mut values[..mid] as *mut [i32];
let end = &mut values[mid..] as *mut [i32];
    
unsafe {
    (&mut *begin, &mut *end)
}
```

In this case, you are constructing two temporary mutable references, *both of which borrow from `values`* (and thus cannot be live at the same time), then “resurrecting” (not a technical term) them from pointers.

Here is a version of the same code which expands some temporaries and syntax sugar:

```rust
use std::ops::IndexMut;

let begin = {
    let v1 = &mut values;
    IndexMut::index_mut(v1, ..mid) as *mut [i32]
};
let end = {
    let v2 = &mut values;
    IndexMut::index_mut(v2, mid..) as *mut [i32]
};

unsafe { (&mut *begin, &mut *end) }
```

Your two pointers `begin` and `end` are derived from `v1` and `v2`, and therefore they are only valid to use as long as `v1` and `v2` are, but `v1` and `v2` conflict with each other.

All that said, I can't say for sure whether it *wouldn't be okay to allow this program* since, after all, it does not create any *actual* mutable aliasing. I am definitely not educated in the theoretical basis of the Stacked Borrows model that Miri checks.

Comment: Note that subslicing a slice is a primitive operation and is not performed through `IndexMut`.